# Nodemailer config works on dev mode and doesn't work on VPS

Tags: nodemailer

Below Nodemailer code works on dev mode on laptop, but doesn't work when deployed on Ubuntu VPS. I get transporter.verify error.

The same code works on another VPS also and also on my Laptop while using dev mode.
Not sure why it is not working on my new VPS.

**Node Methods**

```
async function createPrimaryAccount(reqBody, origin, user) {

  // some code - which works - checked using console.log

  console.log('sending email next');
  // send email
  await sendVerificationEmail(account.email, account.verificationToken, account.clientName, origin);

}


async function sendVerificationEmail(email, verificationToken, clientName, origin) {
  console.log('acct service sendVerificationEmail email, clientName, origin', email, clientName, origin);

  let message;
  const verifyUrl = `${origin}/auth/verify-email?token=${verificationToken}`;
  message =
  `<h3 style="background-color: rgb(63, 81, 181); color: white; padding: 5px 10px">BFSI EDGE's CS Web App: Verification Email</h3>
  <p>This email was sent to you because your email address was used for registering a user on BFSI EDGE's CS Web Application for the client: ${clientName}.</p>
  <p>In case you have not done so, do not click on the below link.</p>
  
  <p>If this is a valid registration, please click the below link to verify your email address:</p>
  <p><a href="${verifyUrl}">CLICK HERE TO VERIFY</a></p>
  <p></p>
  <p>Note that this email cannot receive replies. For any clarification, contact your company's admin.
  </p>
  <p style="background-color: rgb(63, 81, 181); color: white; padding: 5px 10px">BFSI EDGE  Address</p>`;

  
  try {
    await sendEmail({
        to: email,
        subject: 'BFSI-EDGE CS Web-App: Registration Verification required',
        html: message
    }); 

    console.log('Verification email sent.')
    // Getting this log but its not correct as there is an error is sendEmail method

  } catch(err) {
    console.log('Error while sending verification email: ' + err)
  }

}


async function sendEmail({ to, subject, html, from = config.mailServerOptions.auth.user}) {
  console.log('helper sendEmail - from', from)
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(config.mailServerOptions);
  let sendEmail = true;
  transporter.verify(function(error, success) {
    if (error) {
      sendEmail = false;
      console.log('helper sendEmail - transporter.verify error:', error);
      /// GETTING THE ABOVE ERROR

    } else {
      console.log('helper sendEmail - transporter.verify - OKAY')
      if(sendEmail) {
        console.log('helper sendEmail - sending email NOW')
        try {
          transporter.sendMail({ from, to, subject, html });
    
        } catch (err) {
          console.log('helper sendEmail - transporter.sendMail error:', err);
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

**config.mailServerOptions** - I have tried both the below options mail server options required for nodemailer.

```
 "mailServerOptions": {
    "pool": true,
    "host": "smtp.example.com",
    "auth": {
      "user": "some@example.com",
      "pass": "password"
    },
    "tls": {
      "rejectUnauthorized": false
    }
  }


  "mailServerOptions": {
    "service": "gmail",
    "auth": {
      "user": "some@gmail.com",
      "pass": "password"        // USED Google App password here
    },
    "tls": {
      "rejectUnauthorized": false
    }
  }
```

**console.log** : Below are the console log out statements from the above code.

```
sending email next
acct service sendVerificationEmail email, clientName, origin hemantparmarh@gmail.com BFSI EDGE https://demo-cs.bfsiapp.com
helper sendEmail - from hemant@bfsiedge.com
Verification email sent.
helper sendEmail - transporter.verify error: Error: Connection timeout
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (/root/demo-cs/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:784:19)
    at SMTPConnection._onError (/root/demo-cs/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:770:20)
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/root/demo-cs/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:229:22)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  command: 'CONN'
}
```